# Why is $\mathbb{R}$ not a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: vector-spaces

I thought that $\mathbb{R}$ would just be any 1-dimensional line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and that as long as you multiply or add two vectors on that line together, you'd still be in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: elements of $\Bbb R$ are numbers, elements of $\Bbb R^3$ are triples of numbers. A number is not a triple of numbers.

Comment: Ok, but would for example $span(\mathbb{R})$ be a subspace?

Comment: @Void $\operatorname{span}(\Bbb R)$ is just $\Bbb R$.  So no for the same reason.

Comment: @Void You can only form the span if it is a *subset* and as we said, that is the main thing someone could object to. And besides that, for whatever subset you do pick, the span of the subset is always a subspace (sometimes by definition, sometimes by an easy proof from a different definition.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ as $\mathbb R$ vector spaces. For many people, isomorphism is enough to call that copy "$\mathbb R$", but one has to remember that it isn't special and that there are many other such copies.

Someone might object to saying that $\mathbb R$ is a subspace if they want to say that it isn't even a *subset*: $\mathbb R^3$ consists of triples of real numbers while $\mathbb R$ are "1-tuples" of real numbers.